# regex for matching german characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, jupyter-notebook

> Could someone help me on regex to match German words/sentences in
>   python? It does not work on jupyter notebook. I tried same in jsfiddle
>   it works fine. I tried using this below script but does not work

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]\\', re.UNICODE)

print(pattern.search(text))
```

Comment: Your regex will always fail.

Comment: Use `re.findall(r'[^\W\d_]+', text)` to extract any letter word.

Answer (score 3):

Your expression will always fail:

```
\[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]\\
```

Broken down, you require

```
[   # literally
^   # start of the line / text
a-z # literally, etc.
```

The problem is that you require a `[` literally right before the start of a line which can never be true (either there's nothing or a newline). So in the end, either remove the backslash to get a proper character class as in:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+
```

But this will surely not match the words you're looking for (quite the opposite). So either use something as simple as `\w+` or the solution proposed by [**@Wiktor**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets define a range of characters you want to look for, however the '^' negates these characters if it appears within the character class.

If you want to specify the beginning of the line you need to put the '^' before the brackets.

Also you need to add a multiplier behind the class to search for more than just one character in this case:

`r'^[a-zA-Z0-9äöüÄÖÜß]+'`

One ore more characters contained in the brackets are matched as long as they are not seperated by any other character not listed between '[]'

[Here's the link to the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-10)